# PHP Exhaustion of Memory in Foreach

Tags: php, memory, memory-management

I'm suffering from the classic memory exhaustion with the error message

> **Fatal error**:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 11198913 bytes)

I've read about this being what it is: [I'm using too much RAM memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572939/php-memory-exhausted-when-running-through-thousands-of-records). I also tried adding [`gc_collect_cycles`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php) at the end of my loop with no luck and finally I read about [setting variables to null](http://v1.srcnix.com/2010/02/10/7-tips-to-prevent-php-running-out-of-memory/) and [not unset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544779/how-can-i-clear-the-memory-while-running-a-long-php-script-tried-unset). The problem is I'm not sure what I need to unset here.

Consider the following script

```
public function run_all() {
    $accounts = $this->websiteSettings->all();

    foreach ($accounts as $websiteAccount) {
        try {
            $this->run($websiteAccount);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $ticket = new Ticket();
            $ticket->priority = Ticket::PRIORITY_HIGH;
            $ticket->status = Ticket::STATUS_OPEN;
            $ticket->summary = 'Error';
            $ticket->message = $e->getMessage();
            $ticket->create();
        }
    }
}
```

`$this->run` returns boolean, but I don't care about it because this script is being invoked by Cron and whenever an error appears, I save a Ticket to be analyzed by someone. So I don't store the return anywhere. I know deep down `$this->run()` uses somewhat a little bit too much of memory, but it only uses a max of `100MB ~ 200MB` per run. My problem is that this **weekly script** will run on about 100 records and for each time it runs, the RAM in use is not being cleaned.

Bottom line is: Is it possible for me to clean **EVERYTHING** that has been used by `$this->run` at the end of the loop? If so, how?

---

### Edit

Here is the `run` method.

```
public function run(WebsiteSettings $websiteSettings) {
    if (empty($websiteSettings->key)) {
        // @TODO log this because we need to investigate why it was invoked at all 
        return false;
    }

    // Load Settings
    $settings = $websiteSettings->get_website_setting($websiteSettings->website_id, 'express-code', true);
    $has_express_enabled = ($settings && $settings->value);

    // Start the Feed Gateway
    $feedGateway = new feedGateway($websiteSettings->value, $websiteSettings->website_id, $has_express_enabled);
    $feedGateway->run();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What does `$this->run()` do? Does it create/instantiate anything? Are those things it creates being cleared once it's done using them?

Comment: @Benjam it creates a local variable (inside run function) that instantiates other objects and run other methods. But the `run` method is also called in other places and it works great (when being called, just 1 website is executed). I would like to try and settle this inside `run_all` method so I don't change anything on what is already working. My confusion is to why things on `$this->run` is not being automatically cleared after the method is done on each iteration.

Comment: @Benjam I added the `run` method to the question.

Comment: Before the `return true;` in the run method, try either unsetting `$feedGateway` or setting it to `false` or `null`.

Comment: @Benjam I dis with no luck.

Comment: I did it with no luck *